# What are the usage of package_data which is in the setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

I tried to understand what is it for and why we should use it by referring to this site:

https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html

But I still could not understand it. Could anyone show me more examples or ways to use it please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs you point to is outdated and rather terse. Better read this: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files

> The `package_data` argument is a dictionary that maps from package names to lists of glob patterns.

Example:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    ...
    package_data={
        # If any package contains *.txt or *.rst files, include them:
        '': ['*.txt', '*.rst'],
        # And include any *.msg files found in the 'hello' package, too:
        'hello': ['*.msg'],
    }
)
```